# Why does margin-top not work relative to a rotated element?

Tags: css

I have a quick question about CSS3.

When you have a rotated element using `-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);`, and you apply a `margin` to it, is there a reason that it adds the margin to the visual top of the element, rather than the actual top of the element?

In case that wasn't clear, I wrote a JSFiddle to showcase what it does (adds the margin to the visual top): http://jsfiddle.net/jakemulley/Tetjq/

Thanks guys!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by visual top? The margin gets applied to the element, rotation doesn't invert the direction. See this fiddle for more clarity: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/g3C3h/. Keep note of the transform-origin which affects the rotation.

Comment: @abhitalks Am I right in thinking, then, that it affects the transform-origin?

Comment: No. Transform-origin will only affect the rotation. But, the origin and rotation both have no role whatsoever in affecting the element's position which remains the same.

Comment: There, I updated the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/g3C3h/1/) by adding a transition to show how transform-origin affects rotation. But, rotation by itself doesn't affect the elements original position. Margins are still applied to the element as if it weren't rotated at all.

Comment: And this (http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/g3C3h/2/) added the left margin as well.

Comment: @abhitalks The second fiddle shows exactly what I mean. If you rotate it, then add a top margin, it pushes from the TOP, whereas it would be expected to be pushed from the RIGHT (since the right side is *technically* the divs top). Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Imagine the original element is still there. Adding a top margin will shift it from top isn't it? On rotation the element in DOM doesn't invert it's position. It only appears to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're thinking the area above "top" of 50% is the actual top of the element, this is not correct. Because you have a position of "absolute" on .rotated, and a "top" of 50%, this becomes the new "top" to the element. Adding the margin: 10px; is adding the margin to the top of the element as it should. The "visual top" and "actual top" are one in the same.

Edit:
If you use any front-end tools (Firebug is my tool of choice), you can over over the element to see this in action.